# Using unique_ptr in a pair

Tags: c++, c++11

My code:

```
template <typename T>//, T value_if_empty>
class AtomicQueue {
    std::mutex m;
    std::queue<T> q;
    T value_if_empty;

public:
    AtomicQueue(const T& emptyval) : value_if_empty(std::move(emptyval)) {};
    void push(const T& t)
    {
        m.lock();
        q.push(std::move(t));
        m.unlock();
    }
    T pop()
    {
        T a = std::move(value_if_empty);
        m.lock();
        if (!q.empty())
        {
            a = std::move(q.front());
            q.pop();
        }
        m.unlock();
        return a;
    }
};

AtomicQueue<int> A(0);
AtomicQueue<std::unique_ptr<Class1>> B(nullptr);
AtomicQueue < std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<Class1>>> C({ 0,nullptr });
```

This code compiles if I declare just A and B but fails when C is also declared. The error is `'std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<Class1,std::default_delete<Class1>>>::pair(const std::pair<int,std::unique_ptr<Class1,std::default_delete<Class1>>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

The problem seems to be that `std::pair<int, std::unique_ptr<Class1>>` does not have a copy constructor. But the same is true for `std::unique_ptr<Class1>`. So why does the declaration for B compile but C does not? Also, where exactly is the copy constructor being used? 
Sorry if the answer is trivial. I am new to using unique_ptr and move constructors.

Side Question: Is there a cleaner or better way to use value_if_empty? I do not want anything other than nullptr being passed when unique_ptr is being used.

Edit: B does not compile either. (as mentioned in a comment by NathanOliver). So, the question now is how do I remove this error?

Comment: First please always try to use std::lock_guard for mutex rather than handling on your own.

Comment: FWIW, `B` doesn't compile either: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b085cf4460c3672

Comment: Your `pop` function is risky, at you might move several times `value_if_empty`.

Comment: Instead of storing `value_if_empty`, you can `return T();` when the queue is empty.

Comment: @vll: That requires default constructible `T` though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you don't move anything in your function. They recieve `const T&`, but constants cannot be moved. Calling `std::move` on a `const` won't move and does absolutely nothing.

See, move is simply a cast to rvalue. The actual moving happen in the move constructor and move assignment. Such move constructors are declared like this:

```
unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& other);
```

As you can see, it's a non const rvalue reference. Since you cannot call the move constructor, it tries to copy instead. That is the source of the error.

How can you fix it then?

Simply add the required overloads and remove the superfluous moves:

```
template <typename T>
class AtomicQueue {
    std::mutex m;
    std::queue<T> q;
    T value_if_empty;

public:
    // copy, it's an lvalue
    AtomicQueue(const T& emptyval) : value_if_empty(emptyval) {};

    // move, it's an rvalue
    AtomicQueue(T&& emptyval) : value_if_empty(std::move(emptyval)) {};

    void push(const T& t)
    {
        m.lock();
        q.push(t); // same here
        m.unlock();
    }

    void push(T&& t)
    {
        m.lock();
        q.push(std::move(t)); // same here
        m.unlock();
    }
    T pop()
    {
        T a = std::move(value_if_empty);
        m.lock();
        if (!q.empty())
        {
            a = std::move(q.front());
            q.pop();
        }
        m.unlock();
        return a;
    }
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/5yaTT3)

---

Also note that there's a fundamental bug in your class. Look at this line:

```
T a = std::move(value_if_empty);
```

If `pop` is called more than once, `value_if_empty` will be a moved from value and you return it. Your `pop` function can only be called one time before returning unspecified values.

You'll need either to copy `value_if_empty`, default construct it or replace it by a factory function that will return a new value to take if empty.

My favourite solution would be to default construct it.

Here's nonetheless an example with a factory function:

```
template <typename T>
class AtomicQueue {
    std::function<T()> make_empty_value;

public:
    T pop()
    {
        T a = make_empty_value();
        // ...
    }
};
```

Then pass it to your class when creating it:

```
AtomicQueue<std::unique_ptr<Class1>> B([]{ return std::unique_ptr<Class1>{nullptr}; });
```

If you want to avoid the overhead of `std::function`, you can replace the member variable by a template parameter of the lambda type.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
AtomicQueue(const T& emptyval) : value_if_empty(std::move(emptyval)) {}
```

`std::move(emptyval)` is not moving as `emptyval` is `const`.

You would need overloads:

```
AtomicQueue(const T& emptyval) : value_if_empty(emptyval) {}
AtomicQueue(T&& emptyval) : value_if_empty(std::move(emptyval)) {}
```

or change to:

```
AtomicQueue(T emptyval) : value_if_empty(std::move(emptyval)) {}
```

Note: Same applies to `push`.